# How do I use ffmpeg's -filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg version `SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3` and it doesn't allow me to use `-filter_complex`.

It shows:

```
ffmpeg: unrecognized option '-filter_complex'
```

I want to overlay 2 videos, how can I get that option?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Too old

Your version is way too old, and in fact I don't think it even supports any filters if I recall correctly. You can check with `ffmpeg -filters`.

## Get a new `ffmpeg`

To get a recent version you can [compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) or simply [download a static build](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). Users of Ubuntu 15.04 or newer can just install `ffmpeg` from the repository.

## Example command

This example will:

1. Place `video1.mp4` 20 pixels down and 40 pixels over.
2. Place `video2.mp4` in the middle.
3. Combine audio from `video1.mp4` and `video2.mp4`.

   ```
   ffmpeg -i bg.mp4 -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -filter_complex \
   "[0:v][1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,overlay=20:40[bg]; \
    [bg][2:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[v]; \
    [1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" \
   -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
   ```

## Also see

- [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)
- [Superimposing two videos onto a static image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13405214/1109017) for detailed descriptions for each overlay option

Comment: Finally! after 3 years I can write comments :3, Thank You! it really helped me :D

Comment: @MauricioJuanes You should get a "necrocomment" badge.

Answer (score 0):

use `-vf` instead of `-filter_complex` like

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -vf "movie=wlogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Comment: You must be using a super old `ffmpeg`. Your solution should be a last resort if you are unable to upgrade.